# How to set custom alpha in paired t test at libre office calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

In libre-office calc I can perform a paired t test with alpha 0.05. In Excel I can change this value to e.g. 0.01. But Libre-office calc I couldn't find any setting how to change the intial alpha value.

How can change to a different alpha